# I'm getting following "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the WorkspaceController..." error in nest.js

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I get this error

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the WorkspaceController (?). Please make sure that the argument API_SERVICE at index [0] is available in the WorkspaceModule context.

I have this code

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'API_SERVICE',
        transport: Transport.REDIS,
        options: {
          url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
        }
      }
    ]),
    WorkspaceModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
```

**workspace.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [WorkspaceController]
})

export class WorkspaceModule {}
```

**workspace.controller.ts**

```
@Controller()
export class WorkspaceController{
  constructor(@Inject('API_SERVICE') private client: ClientProxy) {}

  @Get("default-languages")
  getDefaultLanguages():Observable<string[]> {
    return this.client.send<any>({cmd:'getDefaultLanguages'},{});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You register the `ClientsModule` inside of `AppModule` which means that controlelrs and providers in `AppModule`'s scope (i.e. in its own `providers` and `controllers` arrays) have access to that provider (`@Inject('API_SERVICE')`), but once you leave to another module's scope (like `WorkspaceModule`), that provider is no longer available. If you need that microservice client in several different modules, I'd suggest making a wrapper module for it, that imports and exports the `ClientsModule`, otherwise, you just need to move the `ClientsMOdule.register` from `AppModule` to `WorkspaceModule`

---

### Example Wrapper

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ClientsModule.register(clientsModuleOptions)],
  exports: [ClientsModule],
})
export class WrapperClientsModule {}
```

It's called [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting)

Comment: hi, I recently come to this issue also, would you like to provide an example of how to create the custom wrapper module for ClientsModule so I can reuse it in all other modules? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make the imported ClientsModule global. Then you can use it and its providers in child modules.

**app.module.ts**

```js
 @Module({
   imports: [
     ClientsModule.register({
       clients: [
         {
           name: 'API_SERVICE',
           transport: Transport.REDIS,
           options: {
             url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
           },
         },
       ],
       isGlobal: true,
     }),
     WorkspaceModule
   ],
   controllers: [AppController],
   providers: [AppService]
 })
```

check **clients-module.interface.d.ts**

```js
    export type ClientsModuleOptions = Array<ClientProviderOptions> | {
        clients: Array<ClientProviderOptions>;
        isGlobal?: boolean;
    };
```